# Display error message if server returns false apache wicket

Tags: java, html, wicket

I'm new to Apache wicket and currently I'm validating username and password on an HTML page. The server returns boolean value true or false depending upon user authorisation.

If it is TRUE then the page is navigating to another page but if it is FALSE I want to display error message on the same page in any feasible form may be in prompt.

How can I do this?

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`FeedbackPanel`](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/panel/FeedbackPanel.html).

There is a lot about it in the internet and you should easily implement it.

Your first place to visit could be: http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/ajax/form